# Tokenizando mal ifstream y ofstream C++

Tags: c++

Estoy trabajando con un amigo usando archivos que requieren el ifstream y ofstream.

Estamos usando un arreglo objeto en la cual guarda todos los datos:

```
nombre, apellido, telefono, correo, numCB, pin, monto
```

El archivo SI se guarda bien, mostrando lo siguiente en el .txt

```
Jorge Salmon 222222 jorge@jorge 11552233 3333 36985
Sol Martinez 15852 sol@sol 15963 2222 3.65411e+07
```

La situación es que lo estamos cargando mal y muestra lo siguiente:

```
0 Jorge Salmon 222222 jorge@jorge 11552233 3333 36985
Sol BOOM 
1 Martinez 15852 sol@sol 15963 2222 3.65411e+07
 36985
Sol BOOM
```

Hemos tratado de varías maneras y, aunque parezca raro este método, este fue nuestro último:

```
    Usuario clientes[20];
    int posActual = 0;

    string nombre, apellido, telefono, correo, numCB, pin, monto;
    double dinero;
    string nombreArray[20], apellidoArray[20], telefonoArray[20], correoArray[20], numCBArray[20], pinArray[20], montoArray[20];

    ifstream datos;
    datos.open("datos.txt");
    if(datos.fail()){
        cout<<"No hay nada en datos.txt"<<endl;
    }else{
        while(!datos.eof()){
            getline(datos, nombre, ' ');
            getline(datos, apellido, ' ');
            getline(datos, telefono, ' ');
            getline(datos, correo, ' ');
            getline(datos, numCB, ' ');
            getline(datos, pin, ' ');
            getline(datos, monto, ' ');


            nombreArray[posActual] = nombre;
            apellidoArray[posActual] = apellido;
            telefonoArray[posActual] = telefono;
            correoArray[posActual] = correo;
            numCBArray[posActual] = numCB;
            pinArray[posActual] = pin;
            montoArray[posActual] = monto;

            posActual++;
        }
        datos.close();

        for(int i=0; i < posActual; i++){
            clientes[i].setNombre(nombreArray[i]);
            clientes[i].setApellido(apellidoArray[i]);
            clientes[i].setTelefono(telefonoArray[i]);
            clientes[i].setCorreo(correoArray[i]);
            clientes[i].setNumCB(numCBArray[i]);
            clientes[i].setPin(pinArray[i]);

            double dinero = stod(montoArray[i]);
            clientes[i].setMonto(dinero);

            cout << i <<" "<< nombreArray[i] << 
                    " "<<apellidoArray[i] << 
                    " "<<telefonoArray[i] << 
                    " "<<correoArray[i] <<
                    " "<<numCBArray[i] <<
                    " "<<pinArray[i] <<
                    " "<<montoArray[i]<<
                    " BOOM "<<endl;
        }
    }
```

Aquí nuestro método para guardar:

```
            ofstream fileS;
            fileS.open("datos.txt");
            for (int i = 0; i < posActual; ++i)
            {

                fileS<<clientes[i].toString()<<endl;

            }

            fileS.close();
```

y aquí el toString del objeto Usuario.

```
string Usuario::toString(){
    stringstream ss;
    ss<<nombre<<" "<<apellido<<" "<<telefono<<" "<<correo<<" "<<numCB<<" "<<pin<<" "<<monto;
    return ss.str();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usar `getline` para leer hasta el primer espacio es matar moscas a cañonazos. `getline` no es una función que se tenga que parar *al final de la línea*, sino que deja de leer cuando se encuentra el separador que le indicas, en este caso un espacio. Fíjate que al leer el último campo, `monto`, no le has dicho que pare al leer un salto de línea... sino un espacio. Eso hace que esa lectura lea más de lo necesario.

Lo que necesitas es usar el operador de extracción:

```
datos >> nombre >> apellido >> telefono >> correo >>  numCB >> pin >> monto;
```

Por otro lado, fíjate que no es necesario copiar todos los datos a un array de `string` para después moverlos al array de `Usuario`. Se puede hacer en un solo paso:

```
double monto;
datos >> nombre >> apellido >> telefono >> correo >>  numCB >> pin >> monto; 
if( datos.eof() )
  break;

Usuario & cliente = clientes[posActual];
cliente.setNombre(nombre);
cliente.setApellido(apellido);
cliente.setTelefono(telefono);
cliente.setCorreo(correo);
cliente.setNumCB(numCB);
cliente.setPin(pin);
cliente.setMonto(monto);
```

Comment: La última parte lo estabamos haciendo como lo mencionas, pero queriamos ver por qué imprimía así, sólo era de prueba. Una duda, ¿donde ponemos exactamente lo que mencionas? De antemano, muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: @frustratedProgrammer esto reemplaza a getline